# C++: Time for filling an array is too long

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, methods

We are writing a method (myFunc) that writes some data to the array. The array must be a field of the class (MyClass).
Example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int dimension);
  ~MyClass();

  void myFunc();

protected:

  float* _nodes;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int dimension){
 _nodes = new float[dimension];
}

void MyClass::myFunc(){
 for (int i = 0; i < _dimension; ++i)
  _nodes[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

The method myFunc is called near 10000 times and it takes near 9-10 seconds (with other methods).

But if we define myFunc as:

```
void MyClass::myFunc(){
 float* test = new float[_dimension];
 for (int i = 0; i < _dimension; ++i)
     test[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

our programm works much faster - it takes near 2-3 seconds (if it's calles near 10000 times).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What compiler are you using and what is the target platform?

Comment: Target platfor is Windows x64, compiler is x86_64-v64-mingw32 4.7.0

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Have you taken a look at what the assembler does? I see no real difference except one test being on the heap, and one on the stack.

Comment: Are you compiling in Release mode?

Comment: We are compiling in Debug-mode

Comment: If this is a `Debug` build all bets are off when accessing member variables.

Comment: unrelated: `test[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;` is the same as `test[i] = i % 2;`

Comment: This 0-1 pattern is obvious, maybe you can make such a static array and copy from it each time. `memcpy` is a lot faster comparing to a for loop.

Comment: unrelated: Use `test[i] = i & 1;` instead of `test[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: this is just for example. You may write only test[i] = 0. It doesn't make sence...

Comment: As @CaptainObvlious states...  run these tests in release mode to see if there are any differences.

Comment: Sigh... Why is it that in 95% of these "why is my code slow" questions, people are compiling without optimizations? What's the point?

Comment: Basically, there is no point in trying to understand performance of code compiled in debug mode, and it is counter productive to try to "fix" these kind of "problems".

Comment: we try to compile it in Release mode, an it take also 9-10 seconds]

Comment: Then focus on Release mode if it shows the same problem. And try what I suggested in my answer in Release mode as well, as I have impression that the example you showed is different from your real code.

Comment: @user2303872 dimension is 24? Calling 100000 times with dimension = 10000 only take me 5 seconds!

Comment: What does this mean: "it takes near 9-10 seconds (with other methods)". What other methods? How do you expect us to analyze methods we haven't seen? Post a minimal, complete example that you have tested in Release mode and seen the issue with, and you may have an actual question here.

Comment: OK guys, if we give you source code (it is realy big), would you analyse it? We told, where is the problem and how we saw the time-changing

Comment: I would try to analyse it.

Comment: here is svn with all source of the project

Comment: The problem is in the method RPcontrol in the class NetworkOperator. Look at the switch-case stattement. The RPcontrol metho is called in the class UNetworkOperator, in the CalcFunctioanl method

Comment: @user2303872 There're nested `for` in RPcontrol, I guess it takes most of the time.

Comment: We try to comment the code-piece with nested for, and it doesn't give us time gain, but if comment the code-piece with swith-case, it give 7-8 seconds time gain

Answer (score 2):

This may help (in either case)

```
for (int i = 0; i < _dimension; )
{
    test[i++] = 0.0f;
    test[i++] = 1.0f;
}
```

I'm assuming `_dimension` is even, but easy to fix if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed up Debug-mode, maybe help the compiler, try

```
void MyClass::myFunc(){
   float* const nodes = _nodes;
   const int dimension = _dimension;
   for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
       nodes[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
}
```

Of course, in reality you should focus on using Release-mode for everything performance-related.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but changing 0 to 0.0f and 1 to to 1.0f (and similar) doesn't help

Comment: @user2303872 The main point was adding and using `nodes` and `dimension` instead of `_nodes` and `_dimension` for the loop!

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, you do not initialise _dimension in the constructor, but use it in MyFunc. So you might be filling millions of entries in the array even though you have only allocated a few thousand entries. In the example that works, you use the same dimension for creating and filling the array so you are probably initialising it correctly in that case..

Just make sure that _dimension is properly initialised.

Answer (score 0):

This is faster on **most** machine.

```
void MyClass::myFunc(){
    float* const nodes = _nodes;
    const int dimension = _dimension;
    if(dimension < 2){
        if(dimension < 1)
            return;
        nodes[0] = 0.0f;
        return;
    }
    nodes[0] = 0.0f;
    nodes[1] = 1.0f;
    for (int i = 2; ; i <<= 1){
        if( (i << 1) < dimension ){
            memcpy(nodes + i, nodes, i * sizeof(float));
        }else{
            memcpy(nodes + i, nodes, (dimension - i) * sizeof(float));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: crashes if dimension is < 2

Comment: It was also easy to think to it in advance. Now it's too late and the plane crashed.

Comment: @6502 I knew it would crash! I just want to post a minimal code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
memset(test, 0, sizeof(float) * _dimension));
for (int i = 1; i < _dimension; i += 2)
{
    test[i] = 1.0f;
}
```

You can also run this piece once and store the array at static location.
For each consecutive iteration you can address the stored data without any computation.

Comment: Passing twice over memory is going to be slower in most modern computers

Comment: @6502 That depends on memset implementation. And it's not twice but 1.5 times